# Date time conversion and extract only time

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

Want to change the class for Time to POSIXlt and extract only the hours minutes and seconds

```
str(df3$Time)
chr [1:2075259] "17:24:00" "17:25:00" "17:26:00" "17:27:00" ...
```

Used the strptime function

```
df33$Time <- strptime(df3$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

This gives the date/time appended

```
> str(df3$Time)
 POSIXlt[1:2075259], format: "2015-08-07 17:24:00" "2015-08-07 17:25:00" "2015-08-07 17:26:00" ...
```

Wanted to extract just the time without changing the POSIXlt class. using the strftime function

```
df3$Time <- strftime(df3$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

but this converts the class back to "char" -

```
> class(df3$Time)
[1] "character"
```

How can I just extract the time with class set to POSIX or numeric...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your data is

```
a <- "17:24:00"

b <- strptime(a, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

you can use `lubridate` in order to have a result of class `integer`

```
library(lubridate)
hour(b)
minute(b)

# > hour(b)
# [1] 17
# > minute(b)
# [1] 24


# > class(minute(b))
# [1] "integer"
```

and you can combine them using

```
# character
paste(hour(b),minute(b), sep=":")

# numeric
hour(b) + minute(b)/60
```

for instance.

I would not advise to do that if you want to do any further operations on your data. However, it might be convenient to do that if you want to plot the results.

Comment: You don't need lubridate to create an integer:   `as.integer(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S"))` works just fine with base R functions.

Comment: So why didn't you post it? That's part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 13):

A *date*time object contains date and time; you cannot extract 'just time'. So you have to think throught what you want:

- POSIXlt is a Datetime representation (as a list of components)
- POSIXct is a different Datetime representation (as a compact numeric)

Neither one omits the Date part.  Once you have a valid object, you can choose to *display* only the time.  But you cannot make the Date part disappear from the representation.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Dirk.  So can you give an example how to display just the HHMMSS in the data.frame?

Comment: Tried both - they both converted class back to character as stated above...That is the challenge                                                                   .> str(df3)
'data.frame': 2075259 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Date                 : Date, format: "2006-12-16" "2006-12-16" ...
 $ Time                 : chr  "17:24:00" "17:25:00" "17:26:00" "17:27:00" ...
 $

Comment: I think you *still* don't understand. A Datetime object contains what it says.  A *short character string* contains the formating.  You can use the former to construct the latter.  The latter will still not be a Datetime object.

Comment: I get what the datetime object is.  Starting with char "17:20:00" I am  using the strptime function to convert  the class.  But the function appends today's date  str(df3$Time) $ Time  : POSIXlt, format: "2015-08-07"2015-08-07 17:20:00" - I don't want today's date shown in the table. Just the time! My question again is not what is Datetime object, it is that why cant I just extract the HHMMSS WITHOUT changing the calss to character - are you saying that is just not possible?

Comment: Try `format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S")` which, seconds ago, gave me "073007" as it is just past 7:30am where I live.   And yes, that will give you **character** because that is what `strftime()` and `format()` return.  Let's stop here and I suggest you step back and read up on the _ample_ available documentation.  Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

A "modern" `tidyverse` answer to this is to use `hms::as_hms()`

For example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

as_hms(1)
#> 00:00:01
as_hms("12:34:56")
#> 12:34:56
```

or, with your example data:

```
x <- as.POSIXlt(c("17:24:00", "17:25:00", "17:26:00", "17:27:00"), format = "%H:%M:%S")

x
#>[1] "2021-04-10 17:24:00 EDT" "2021-04-10 17:25:00 EDT" "2021-04-10 17:26:00 EDT" "2021-04-10 17:27:00 EDT"

as_hms(x)
# 17:24:00
# 17:25:00
# 17:26:00
# 17:27:00
```

See also docs here:
https://hms.tidyverse.org/reference/hms.html

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `chron` package to extract just times of the day:

```
library(chron) 

# current date/time in POSIXt format as an example
timenow <- Sys.time()

# create chron object "times"
onlytime <- times(strftime(timenow,"%H:%M:%S"))

> onlytime
[1] 14:18:00
> onlytime+1/24
[1] 15:18:00
> class(onlytime)
[1] "times"
```

Answer (score 7):

This is my idiom for getting just the timepart from a datetime object.  I use `floor_date()` from lubridate to get midnight of the timestamp and take the difference of the timestamp and midnight of that day.  I create and store a `hms` object provided with `lubridate` (I believe) in dataframes because the class has formatting of `hh:mm:ss` that is easy to read, but the underlying value is a numeric value of seconds.  Here is my code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

# Create timestamps
#
# Get timepart by subtacting the timestamp from it's floor'ed date, make sure
# you convert to seconds, and then cast to a time object provided by the
# `hms` package.
# See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hms/versions/0.4.2/topics/hms
dt <- tibble(dt=c("2019-02-15T13:15:00", "2019-02-19T01:10:33") %>% ymd_hms()) %>%
  mutate(timepart = hms::hms(as.numeric(dt - floor_date(dt, "1 day"), unit="secs")))

# Look at result
print(dt)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   dt                  timepart
#>   <dttm>              <time>  
#> 1 2019-02-15 13:15:00 13:15   
#> 2 2019-02-19 01:10:33 01:10

# `hms` object is really a `difftime` object from documentation, but is made into a `hms`
# object that defaults to always store data in seconds.
dt %>% pluck("timepart") %>% str()
#>  'hms' num [1:2] 13:15:00 01:10:33
#>  - attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"

# Pull off just the timepart column
dt %>% pluck("timepart")
#> 13:15:00
#> 01:10:33

# Get numeric part.  From documentation, `hms` object always stores in seconds.
dt %>% pluck("timepart") %>% as.numeric()
#> [1] 47700  4233
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Looking back, I could have articulated the question better. The question was posed when I had very little experience. But @mpettis answered the question just right. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  The way you originally posted is exactly how I had thought about it, so I don't have any criticisms about the phrasing.  I posted this because I came to this post before I had an answer, wasn't completely happy with the other answers, found the `hms` package, and decided to leave this answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in POSIX format, the only way would be to leave it as it is, and extract just the "time" part everytime you display it. But internally it will always be date + time anyway.
If you want it in numeric, however, you can simply convert it into a number.
For example, to get time as number of seconds passed since the beginning of the day:

```
df3$Time=df3$Time$sec + df3$Time$min*60 + df3$Time$hour*3600
```