# how to read only time in a data frame

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a data frame of date, time. I read it with as.POSIXct, but i don't need the dates, i only need the time. then i want to make box plot with the times that i have. how i can only read the time data?

```
C1
   13/07/2017 15:15
   13/07/2017 15:02
   13/07/2017 14:40
   13/07/2017 15:15
   13/07/2017 15:10
   13/07/2017 15:23
   13/07/2017 14:56
   13/07/2017 15:15
   13/07/2017 15:15
   13/07/2017 14:56
   13/07/2017 14:56
   13/07/2017 14:56
   13/07/2017 15:15
   13/07/2017 15:02
   13/07/2017 15:10

df <-  read.csv2(file="DF.csv")


df <- as.POSIXct(df$C1, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

Comment: You need to `format` the variable after reading it as `POSIXct`. Example: `as.POSIXct(df$C1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %>% 
  format("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: i formatted but still the dates will be appear

Comment: Once you use `format()` function, the output is a string of HMS, so that can't happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date time conversion and extract only time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876962/date-time-conversion-and-extract-only-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your data frame and apply the function `as.POSIXct()` to better replicate your situation.

You can use the `strftime()` function to split the column and then the function `times()` to create a chronological object.

```
df = data.frame(C1 = c("13/07/2017 15:15","13/07/2017 15:02","13/07/2017 14:40","13/07/2017 15:15",
                   "13/07/2017 15:10","13/07/2017 15:23","13/07/2017 14:56","13/07/2017 15:15",
                   "13/07/2017 15:15","13/07/2017 14:56","13/07/2017 14:56","13/07/2017 14:56",
                   "13/07/2017 15:15","13/07/2017 15:02","13/07/2017 15:10"))  #replicate data frame
df <- as.POSIXct(df$C1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") #apply  function to create a POSIXct object
```

Then the function you need to apply to your data frame it's the following:

```
library(chron)
time <- times(strftime(df, format="%H:%M:%S")) #select only time and create a times object
```

This is results:

```
time
[1] 15:15:00 15:02:00 14:40:00 15:15:00 15:10:00 15:23:00 14:56:00 15:15:00 15:15:00 14:56:00 14:56:00 14:56:00 15:15:00 15:02:00 15:10:00
class(time)
[1] "times"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)
df$C1 <- hm(df$C1)
```