# strptime() in R converts timestamp class from Posixct to character

Tags: r, timestamp, character, posixct, strptime

When i strip date and time using `strptime()`it converts my time from class `POSIXct` to `character`.

```
> head(data)
           timestamps value
1 2017-10-01 00:00:00 8.424
2 2017-10-01 01:00:00 7.832
3 2017-10-01 02:00:00 6.320
4 2017-10-01 03:00:00 6.696
5 2017-10-01 04:00:00 5.448
6 2017-10-01 05:00:00 4.992

> data$time <- format(data$timestamps,"%H:%M:%S")
> str(data)
'data.frame':   226 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ timestamps: POSIXct, format: "2017-10-01 00:00:00" "2017-10-01 01:00:00" "2017-10-01 02:00:00" ...
 $ value     : num  8.42 7.83 6.32 6.7 5.45 ...
```

> `$ time      : chr  "00:00:00" "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "03:00:00" ...`

You can see it converts time to `character`. How do i strip time with same class `POSIXct`?

This [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876962/date-time-conversion-and-extract-only-time) gives how to convert it to Integer and take hours, minutes values alone. **I want my timestamp to convert it to Posixct and Not Integer**. Also read the line given in that link.**I would not advise to do that if you want to do any further operations on your data. However, it might be convenient to do that if you want to plot the results.**

And this doesn't work either : `as.integer(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S"))`

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876962/date-time-conversion-and-extract-only-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date time conversion and extract only time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876962/date-time-conversion-and-extract-only-time)

Comment: I have already seen that, It doesn't work for me

Comment: Added my 2cents in the answer. Doesn't seem to have any other work around.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is to convert the character time into POSIXlt object (which would append current date to it)

```
> strptime('10:12:00',format='%H:%M:%S')
[1] "2017-10-11 10:12:00 IST"
> class(strptime('10:12:00',format='%H:%M:%S'))
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
>
```

Alternatively, `lubridate` to individually extract Hour, Min, Seconds (as integers) and playing around with them!

Comment: Thanks. But i would like to have the time alone. I don't want date to be included in that. Is there a way to convert  `$ time      : chr  "00:00:00" "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "03:00:00" ...`  to Posixct or posixlt

Comment: Ideally, POSIX objects will always be with Date and Time. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700025/5086335